# How can I determine Einstein's temperature for a solid?

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics

There is an unknown parameter, Einstein's temperature (or Einstein's frequency), in Einstein's model for solids. If I'm given some experimental values for the specific heat capacity of a solid in different temperatures, how can I determine Einstein's temperature for that solid?

Comment: Compare to the calculated values of $c_v$ as a function of temperature as computed in the Einstein model.